# Javascript code execution explanation wanted and unseen Javascript syntax: (superman.name && superman.save)();

Tags: javascript, object, scope, this

I recently came across this snippet of code in JavaScript.
The code prints 4 lines as the output:

```
Save Martha
Save Lois
Save Lois
Save Martha
```

I understand how line 2 of the output was derived. I do not, however, understand how lines 1, 3 & 4 were derived. I would like an explanation as to how the JS engine came to compute lines 1, 3, & 4.

Furthermore, the syntax `(superman.name && superman.save)();` is something that I am seeing for the first time in JS & would like to know how the code is executed in this line.

From what I have learned so far, I got to know that this has something to do with how JS deals with the `this` keyword and what value is assigned to `this` at any point of code execution.

```js
this.name = 'Martha'

let superman = {
  name: 'Lois',
  save: function() {
    console.log(`Save ${this.name}`)
  }
}

function saver(save) {
  save()
}

(superman.name && superman.save)();

superman.save();

(superman.save)();

saver(superman.save);
```

Answer (score 1):

When a function is invoked, if it's not bound or an arrow function, its `this` is the parent object of the function expression, if any. Eg

```
foo.bar()
^^^
```

But if you extract a function into a standalone variable or argument before calling it:

```
function saver(save) {
  save()
}
```

it's not called as part of an object, so there's no `this`. Similarly. if the function isn't called as part of an object, but as an intermediate expression:

```
(superman.name && superman.save)();
```

there's no `this` either.

The plain

```
(superman.save)();
```

preserves the `this` of `superman` because there's no intermediate expression inside the parentheses.

Comment: what do you mean by "if it's not bound" in the first line of your answer?

Comment: Like with `.bind`. It's not being used here.